# Click trigger on anchor that is loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use the ajax trigger on an anchor that is dynamically generated by ajax.

This is what I tried with no success and no errors:

```
        $('.excelDL').live('click', function(e){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'exceldl.php',
                data: $('#myForm').serialize(), 
                type: 'POST', 
                success: function(data){
                    $('.xldl').html(data);
                    attach = $('.xldl a').attr("href");

                    $('.xldl a').trigger('click');
                }
            });
        });
```

I believe it is because I am inserting new elements into the DOM using AJAX that trigger is not working, this is why I tried using `live`. I am not really sure how to proceed and solve this problem.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? If you're on jQuery 1.9 the live method has been removed and you should use the 'on'

Comment: Once `.live()` is sorted out ... What does the line `attach = $('.xldl a').attr("href");` achieve? Are you aware that `$('.xldl a').trigger('click');` will trigger all `.xldl a` elements on the page, not just the freshly added one?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am aware of that, there is only one anchor in `.xldl`.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, The reason I believe the answer below does not work is because excelDL is a static element. The element that needs the `on` event is the xldl, any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "on" instead of "live"

```
    $(document).on('click','.excelDL',function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'exceldl.php',
            data: $('#myForm').serialize(), 
            type: 'POST', 
            success: function(data){
                $('.xldl').html(data);
                attach = $('.xldl a').attr("href");

                $('.xldl a').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    });
```

jquery on documentation : http://api.jquery.com/on/

jquery live is deprecated after 1.7

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, this does not work. The event is never triggered :/

Comment: The reason I believe this does not work is because excelDL is a static element. The element that needs the `on` event is the `xldl`.

Comment: The code above will throw an error. An erroneous `)` needs to be removed and the arguments are in the wrong order. The first line should read `$(document).on('click', '.excelDL', function(e){`